# terminal command to open new chromium tab

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium

I would like to open the page chrome://newtab (a.k.a. the "New Tab" page) in an existing chromium window using the command-line.

this opens a new window with an empty tab:

```
chromium-browser chrome://newtab
```

this opens a new tab with the entered URL:

```
chromium-browser www.google.com
```

It seems that the first terminal command doesn't recognize newtab as a URL like it does in the second one. Can the call be modified somehow to open a new tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a New Tab and look at the Developer Tools - Sources tab. URL for New Tab is:

```
chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html
```

This will open a new tab in existing Chromium instance:

```
chromium chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html
```

Comment: This works better than the originally accepted solution, especially concerning that weird xdotool behavior.

Answer (score 8):

A couple of options to consider...

1) Find an existing instance of Chromium, activate the window, and send Ctrl+t to open a new tab:

`xdotool search --onlyvisible --name 'Chromium' windowactivate --sync key --clearmodifiers --window 0 ctrl+t`

2) Open the about:blank page in a new tab:

`chromium-browser 'about:blank'`

#1 does exactly what you want.
#2 is cheesy.

Comment: In Gnome 3, when I create a Custom Shortcut (Super+T) to execute above shell command, the "Super" modifier "sticks". Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: @AndreasHacker, try removing the --clearmodifiers flag from your command line. Documentation here: https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#clearmodifiers

If that doesn't work, please post a new question specific to xdotool on Gnome 3. Note that there are known issues with xdotool with Walyland with Gnome 3.

Comment: to further clarify this: #2 is "cheesy" because it does not focus chromium by default